# Apache reverse proxy redirects every address to the same vhost

Tags: apache-httpd, virtual-machine, apache-virtualhost, virtual-host

I have installed a webapp in a virtual machine on my server (both running Debian 8 and Apache2). I used a reverse proxy on the host machine to redirect all the connections made to https://webapp.domain.com to the internal address of the webapp on the virtual machine (http://192.168.100.101/webapp) using the following vhost configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName webapp.domain.com
ServerAlias www.webapp.domain.com
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyVerify none
ProxyPass / http://192.168.100.101/webapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.100.101/webapp/
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/webapp.domain.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webapp.domain.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webapp.domain.com/fullchain.pem

ServerAdmin unavailable
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhosts/webapp_access.log combined
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhosts/webapp_error.log
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>

<Proxy *>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

However if I try to connect to any address on the ip of the host machine, I end up seeing the webapp on the virtual machine (i.e., let's assume that the public IP of the host machine is 10.10.10.10, connecting to https://10.10.10.10/anything shows me the webapp on the virtual machine).

How can I prevent this from happening? Could it be the guest machine configuration the cause of this?

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is here

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.100.101/webapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.100.101/webapp/
```

You are saying that every url using "/" needs to go to anotherIp/webapp/ .

Specifying webapp should solve the problem:

```
ProxyPass /webapp http://192.168.100.101/webapp 
ProxyPassReverse /webapp http://192.168.100.101/webapp
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe I should use webapp.domain.com instead of /webapp? Since I expect users to connect to webapp.domain.com in order to access the webapp. Makes sense?

Comment: You are already there, i mean webapp.domain.com is your localhost you don't need to specify that.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. webapp.domain.com should show what is at 192.168.100.101 (regardless to whether it is webapp.domain.com or webapp.domain.com/webapp). The problem is that 10.10.10.10 (that is the ip of the host machine) shows what is at 192.168.100.101.

Comment: try with this: ProxyPass / "http://192.168.100.101/"
ProxyPassReverse / "http://192.168.100.101/"

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue